# Проблема с кэшированием

Tags: php

Ситуация такая, есть страница php, к примеру, `<? echo "test"; ?>`. После редактирования кода, к примеру, `<? echo "11111111"; ?>` не реагирует никак на изменения. Такое ощущение, что она закешировалась, и так все страницы не реагируют на изменения, только на удаление.

Помогите, кто может, спасибо....

Comment: cash - бабло. кэш - cache.

Comment: Попробуйте так : <?php ваш код... ?>

Comment: а ешё советую подтянуть русский язык, просто если человек на русском так пишет, то в коде на другом языке возможны так же ошибки в написании :)

Comment: да спасибо за ответ я ожидал что ни буть в роде about mem cash

Comment: ник себе смени
!!!!!!!

Comment: Больше восклицательных, тогда вас обязательно услышат.

По теме - Ctrl+F5

Comment: а че, еще не сделали минуса в комментах?:)

Comment: Если вы ничего в memcache не ложите, то там ничего не появится, проблема в чем-то другом, возможно действительно, как выше написали, стоит попробывать отказаться от использования "short tags"

Comment: @zippp, теперь мне интересно, как это может быть связано с не-обновлением страницы) код-то один раз исполняется.

Comment: бывает и так что хостер меняет сервак без предупреждения, и ты меняешь файлы на старом серваке, а сайт то лежит на новом!

Answer (score 1):

Бывает еще возможно такое иногда - когда скрипт копируешь из одного php файла в другой, в браузере видишь работу уже скопированного кода, а изменения проводишь в старом файле. И глаза на лоб лезут как оно так? Я меняю а оно не меняется! А вот так и получается! В основном уже под конец рабочего дня))) Если 5 минут назад не кешировалос, а тут прям вдруг. Нипанятна)